# Download after completing the request - vue-json-excel

Tags: vue.js, callback, promise, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using the **vue-json-excel** library that helps me download data from a json.

where in the view of the vue I have:

```
<div class="column is-narrow" @click="btDispatch">
    <json-excel
      class   = "button is-primary"
     :data   = "routes"
     :fields = "json_fields_routes"
     :name    = "`descarga-rutas.xls`">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span><span>Descargar entregas</span>
   </json-excel>
```

Where:**data = "routes"** is the json that will be downloaded:

```
data () {
  return {
     json_fields_routes: {
       ruta_id: 'id',
       fecha: 'date',
       estado_codigo: 'route_state',
       estado: 'estado',
       vehículo: 'vehicle',
       conductor_codigo: 'worker.id',
       conductor_nombre: 'worker.name',
       hora_inicio: 'date_start_web',
       hora_fin: 'date_end_web',
       entregas: 'dispatches_count',
       pendientes: 'pendientes',
       entregados: 'entregados',
       parciales: 'parciales',
       no_entregados: 'noEntregados',
     },
     json_meta: [
      [
        {
          key: 'charset',
          value: 'utf-8',
        },
      ],
    ],
  }
}
```

According to the documentation, I must do this to download Excel and it works correctly. The problem I have is that it is downloaded when there is existing data, but I am working with data that comes from the server and previously loaded the data in the load () but it takes a long time when there is a large amount of data to enter that section of the page, so I prefer that the download button compile the data and then download.

So far I have:

```
methods: {
  btRoute() {
        this.axios.post('/routesdownload/filter_route/', this.params)
            .then((response) => {
              this.routes = response.data.results;
              for (let i = 0; i < this.routes.length; i++) {
                this.routes[i].pendientes = this.filterByStatus(this.routes[i].dispatches, 1);
                this.routes[i].entregados = this.filterByStatus(this.routes[i].dispatches, 2);
                this.routes[i].parciales = this.filterByStatus(this.routes[i].dispatches, 3);
                this.routes[i].noEntregados = this.filterByStatus(this.routes[i].dispatches, 4);
                this.routes[i].date = moment(this.routes[i].date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
                if (this.routes[i].date_start_web && this.routes[i].date_end_web != null) {
                  this.routes[i].date_start_web
                  = moment(this.routes[i].date_start_web).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
                  this.routes[i].date_end_web
                  = moment(this.routes[i].date_end_web).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
                } else {
                  this.routes[i].date_start_web = '-';
                  this.routes[i].date_end_web = '-';
                }
                if (this.routes[i].route_state === 1) {
                  this.routes[i].estado = 'Borrador';
                } else if (this.routes[i].route_state === 2) {
                  this.routes[i].estado = 'Publicado';
                } else if (this.routes[i].route_state === 3) {
                  this.routes[i].estado = 'Iniciado';
                } else {
                  this.routes[i].estado = 'Terminado';
                }
              }
            });
      },
}
```

But this simply brings the data and the weapon according to the need, but how could you after completing the application, call the function you download with this library? I could do it with a **callback** or a **promise**, but how can I call that download function?

Comment: Which phase is slow; downloading the data or processing it? Run a performance test and work out where you need to concentrate your effort.

Comment: It doesn't have that capability. If you want to work with it then pass on the data you want to download through a computed property and don't let the user to click the download button until your data loading is finished. Otherwise you'll have to look into some other library or you can make your own (I opted for this solution)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @NafiulIslam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suposed it's a little late response, but the new version of vue-json-excel support a callback prop to fetch data before download the file.

```
<json-excel
  class   = "button is-primary"
  fetch = "MyCallbackFetchData"
 :fields = "json_fields_routes">

 Descargar Archivo
</json-excel>
```

The callback can run with the async...await option so you can use asyncrounous calls like:

```
methods:{
  async MyCallbackFetchData(){
      return await axios.get('myapiurl');
  }
}
```

IMPORTANT: This option only works when the prop data it's undefined. If data it's defined then the file it's generate with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently, the library does not have that functionality.
then to the component I put a **ref**:

```
<json-excel
      ref="droute"
      class   = "button is-primary"
     :data   = "routes"
     :fields = "json_fields_routes"
     :name    = "`descarga-rutas.xls`">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span><span>Descargar entregas</span>
   </json-excel>
```

and when the promise ends(has the data loaded):

```
this.$refs.droute.$el.click();
```

I call the component and download.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i'm using two button, one for load data and one for donwload. and also its much easier to implement

Comment: So you mean the user should use those two buttons in order?